# How to insert value on junction table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, phpmyadmin

Hi i am having trouble inserting data on a junction table.

My update Query is working well

```
sql = "UPDATE student_subject " & _
            " INNER JOIN subject_bsit " & _
            " ON subject_bsit.subject_id = student_subject.sub_id " & _
            " SET grade = "1" where student_subject.student_id= "1235" AND student_subject.sub_id = 1"
```

This is my SQL statement in inserting data in the junction table did i do something wrong cause i'm getting syntax error

```
sql = "INSERT INTO student_subject (student_id,sub_id,grade) " & _
            " INNER JOIN student " & _
            " ON student.StudentID = student_subject.student_id " & _
            " VALUES ("1235","4","1.25")" & _
            " where student_subject.student_id= "1235""
```

What i want to do is to have the **studentID 1235** to have a **subject_id 4** which is networking.

This is my Database table

```
student Table

    -----------------------
    |studentID | FullName |
    -----------------------
    |1234      | John    |
    |1235      | Michael |
    |1236      | Bryce   |

"subject_bsit"

    -----------------------------------------
    |subject_id| subject_name  |  pre_id    |
    -----------------------------------------
    |    1     | Programming 1 |    NULL     |
    |    2     | Networking    |    NULL     |
    |    3     | Algorithm     |    NULL     |
    |    4     | Physical Educ |    NULL     |
    |    5     | Programming 2 |     1       |

This is the Junction table to connect the 
    two now.

"student_subject"

    -------------------------------------
    | student_id | subject_id | Grade   |
    -------------------------------------
    |   1235     |      1     |   NULL  |
    |   1235     |      2     |    2    |
    |   1235     |      3     |    1    |
    |   1234     |      1     |   2.25  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error because you are using the `INSERT` statement incorrectly.

See here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html for more details.

You are able to use `JOIN` in your `UPDATE` statement because it is part of the `[where_clause]` parameter. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

You should be using `INSERT INTO [table1] SELECT [column] FROM [table2]` like below to insert values into a table based on values found in other tables.

```
INSERT INTO student_subject (student_id,sub_id,grade) 
SELECT student.StudentId, 4, null
FROM student
WHERE student.studentID = 1235;
```

you can add the specific `JOIN` statement in the `SELECT` statement following the `FROM student` line for your actual code.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfa24/1)